# Highlighting active tab after overriding the active class (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues highlighting the active tab of a navbar (bootstrap)

The page works like so:

1. User Adds a product
2. Once added a new tab will appear with the products name shown
3. The user can then click on that tab to checkoff checkboxes belonging to that product
4. Keep adding products and/or deleting products

During step 3 the tab color is updated to match the color of the progress bar within the tab.

My problem is that I want the tab to have a different color when it is selected (active) and then revert back to the progress bar color once another tab is clicked.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#new').keypress(function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if (key == 13) {
            AddTabFromTemplate($('#newProductName').val());
        }
    })

    $('#btnAddNew').on('click', function () {
        AddTabFromTemplate($('#newProductName').val());
    });

    // Listen for all js-deletetab in the context of #tab-content, even if the tab panels are dynamically generated
    $('#tab-content').on('click', '.js-deletetab', function () {
        // Find the parent tab-pane's ID and call the Remove Tab function
        RemoveTab($(this).parents('.tab-pane').attr('id'));
    });
});

function AddTabFromTemplate(newID) {
    // Sanitize ID in here is fine
    var domID = newID.replace(/ /g, '_');

    // Make a copy of the template
    $newTab = $('#template').clone();
    $newTab.attr('id', domID);

    // Insert the new tab page right before our "new" tab.
    $newTab.insertBefore('#new');

    // Create the tab item, too
    var tab = $('<li role="presentation"><a href="#' + domID + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">' + newID + '</a></li>').insertBefore('#newTab');
    tab = tab.find('a');

    //Update ProgressBar
    ProgressBar($newTab, tab);

}

//Uses the newly created tab to target its progress bar
function ProgressBar( currentTab, liTab){
    //Grab all the checkboxes
    var checkboxes = currentTab.find('.checkbox');
    liTab.css({ 
        'background-color': '#D9534F',// red = #D9534F;
        'color': 'white'
    });
    //Grab the Landing required checkboxes
    var landDisp = currentTab.find('.land-display');
    var landingPage = currentTab.find('.req');
    var landReq = false;
    landDisp.css('display', 'none');

    //If landing page is required display the rest of the checkboxes
    //  and updated the landReq bool
    landingPage.on('click', function(){
        if(landReq === false){
            landDisp.toggle();
            landReq = true;
        }
        else if(landReq === true){
            landDisp.toggle();
            landReq = false;
        }
    })

    checkboxes.on('click', function(){
        var emptyValue = 0;
        //Checks each checkbox in the tab for checked or not checked
        checkboxes.each(function() {                
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                //If the landing required checkbox is checked update 
                //  the value of the emptyValue for progress bar
                if(landReq === false){
                    emptyValue += 5.3;
                }
                else if(landReq === true){
                    emptyValue += 4.4;
                }
            }
        });

        //Progressbar update section
        if(emptyValue > 30 && emptyValue < 70 ){
            currentTab.find('.progress-bar').removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
            currentTab.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-warning');
            liTab.css('background-color', '#F0AD4E');// yellow = #F0AD4E;
        }
        else if(emptyValue >= 70){
            currentTab.find('.progress-bar').removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
            currentTab.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-success');
            liTab.css('background-color', '#5CB85C');// green = #5CB85C;
        }
        currentTab.find('.progress-bar').css('width', emptyValue + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', emptyValue);
    });
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/BzbvPB)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the answer? Was it helpfull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
li.active a {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

Here is a [working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNvLLK).

The background color for the `a` tag will be black as long as the `li` has the `active` class. Using the `!important` we overrider the inline-style definition of that `a` tag.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt think it would be as easy as using !important, i guess I was trying to somehow do it using jquery since that is how I was updating the tab in the first place. But this is a solid solution for this little project